# incompatible pointer types to xx from NSString

Tags: nsstring, uitextfield

this might be an obvious question to most people but i am very confused with this warning.

i am trying to get a value from UI to a class

```
request.EMPLID = @"KU0006";  // insert your zip code here.
```

but obviously xcode won't allow be to do so and i got the error incompatible pointer types assigning to 'ONT_EMPLIDTypeShape' from NSString

where 'ONT_EMPLIDTypeShape' is a class generated wsdl2objc

how can i assign the value from UI to the class in order to submit WSDL to system to get values? any suggestion help would be much appreciated